# run jQuery if anchor in div contains text in anchor in previous div

Tags: jquery

Is this even possible in jQuery?

Basically I have two divs

```
<div class="first">
    <a href="#">Some random link</a>, 
    <a href="#">second random link</a>, 
    <a href="#">other random link</a>
</div>
<div class="second">
    <a href="#">second random link</a>
    <a href="#">third random link</a>
    <a href="#">tenth random link</a>
</div>
```

What I want is if the text in an anchor in the 2nd div matches text in an anchor from the first div (different on every page), run jQuery (to add a class to just the anchor in the second div that contains the matching text).

Comment: Run jQuery to make the check AND set the anchor :)

Comment: Which anchor do you want to add the class to?

Comment: there are anchors in two divs, you will have to parse through them and then check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$.each()` to loop over the anchors in the second DIV. You can then test whether its text is in any of the anchors in the first DIV.

```js
$("#doit").click(function() {
  $(".second a").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if ($(".first a:contains(" + text + ")").length) {
      $(this).addClass("matched");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.matched {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
  <a href="#">Some random link</a>,
  <a href="#">second random link</a>,
  <a href="#">other random link</a>
</div>
<div class="second">
  <a href="#">second random link</a>
  <a href="#">third random link</a>
  <a href="#">tenth random link</a>
</div>
<button id="doit">Click to test</button>
```

Comment: If there were multiple links in the second div, would this add it to all of them? Any way to only add the class to the anchor that contains the matching text? The first div usually contains about 100 entries, and the second div has links loaded from an ajax search, and I'm trying to make it obvious if any of the links are already in the first box and wont need clicked lol

Comment: Please update the question to show what you're really trying to do. My answer is just for two DIVs, because that's what the second line of the question says.

Comment: You said you wanted to compare the text in the DIVs, not the test in the links. You REALLY need to clarify the question.

Comment: Clarified the question. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Check this out it will work for you.

```
if($( ".first:contains('"+$('.second').text()+"')" ).length > 0) {
  //apply your logic here..
}
```